# utf-8 filename are ruined when uploading through IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, upload, encoding, utf-8

When I upload files with UFT-8 file name through IIS on my Windows Server file names are ruined. (They are changed as if they are encoded in ASCII and therefore they are no more accessible). I Wonder if there is any work around for this problem.
I should also mention that my Windows Server doesn't have any issue with UTF-8 file names and I can create them through RDP or FTP. The problem only occurs when uploading through  IIS.

> Configuration:
>   OS: Windows Server 2008 SP1
>   Web Server: IIS 7.5
>   Uploading by PHP script executed through fastcgi

Comment: You need to examine your PHP script and make sure it handles UTF-8 filenames correctly.

Comment: It's a good idea; but may I ask which part of the PHP configuration may cause the issue? Woul you mind suggesting anything?

Comment: Your problem is the file wrapper for php in IIS is in ISO-8859-1.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525830/how-do-i-use-filesystem-functions-in-php-using-utf-8-strings

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you may face a confirmed problem when using FastCGI module with a URL containing UTF-8 characters.

The FastCGI module in IIS 7.5 uses ASCII encoding.

Microsoft has published a Hotfix for this :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2277918/en-us